# Add css to image displayed from database

Tags: css, image

Could someone help with this little problem. I have tried adding the bootstrap class img-responsive to images that are stored in a database but with no luck.

Here is the existing code I have...

```
<?php

  if(trim($modelQ['illustration'] != "")){
    print "<img src=\"illustrations/{$modelQ['illustration']}\" width=\"558\"/>";
  } elseif(trim($modelQ['bosal_img'] != "")){
    print "<img src=\"illustrations/bosal/{$modelQ['bosal_img']}\" width=\"558\"/>";
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a class like this

```
<?php  

  if(trim($modelQ['illustration'] != "")) {
        print "<img class="nameofyourclass" src=\"illustrations/{$modelQ['illustration']}\" width=\"558\"/>";
      } elseif(trim($modelQ['bosal_img'] != "")){ 
        print "<img class="nameofyourclass" src=\"illustrations/bosal/{$modelQ['bosal_img']}\" width=\"558\"/>";
      }

?>
```

and then you can do

```
img.nameofyourclass{
   //your css
}
```

or you can enclose the print in a div and...

```
.classofthediv img{
    //your css
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/mrexhaus/public_html/page_exhausts.php on line 41